# Not working Laravel and Ajax data insert in to the database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.7 and Ajax to insert data and display in the following blade file,

```
 <table border="0">
    <th colspan="6">Members</th>
    <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    </tr>

    @foreach($member as $value)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->age}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->address}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>

    <!--insert data-->
    <table border="0">
    <th colspan="2">Insert</th>
    <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="age"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" id="insert">Insert</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    {{ csrf_field() }}

$('#insert').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'insertdata',
        data:{
            '_token':$('input[name:_token').val(),
            'name':$('input[name:name').val(),
            'age':$('input[name:age').val(),
            'email':$('input[name:email').val(),
            'address':$('input[name:address').val(),
        },
        success:function(data){
            window.location.reload();
        },
    });
});
```

My HomeController is like this,

```
public function index()
    {
        $member = membersmodel::all();
        return view('home.index')->with('member',$member);
    }

    public function insertdata(Request $request)
    {
        $member = New membersmodel();
        $member->name = $request->name;
        $member->age = $request->age;
        $member->email = $request->email;
        $member->address = $request->address;
        $member->save();
        return response()->json($member);
    }
```

and route is,

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');

Route::post('insertdata','HomeController@insertdata');
```

but when I insert data in the insert table and click  insert button, anything not happens. not saving data or displaying. No, any error occurred.how can fix this problem?

Comment: There are errors you just don't see them. It's never "blank". Try to debug it. In your controller try to `print_r($request->all());` and see if you actually access your controller, `console.log();` your data to see if the error is in the view etc etc. Always something happens.

Comment: Where's the AJAX code? What happens instead?

Comment: @NicoHaase please see My updated answer there is ajax part

Comment: @pr1nc3 how can I use `print_r($request->all());` and `console.log();`in my codes?

Comment: In your controller in the insertdata function you can print_r(); and die(); or use dd($request->all); doesn't matter which but if you actually see your data that means that your ajax works and you access the controller. Otherwise the issue is in the FE side. Then you have to console.log(); data to see if you actually retrieve values from your form etc etc. Add break points in the code and take it step by step so you figure out where the actual problem is.

Comment: on what browser you use, open the console and check the network tab. what status code does insertdata call have?

Comment: @ElenaRoman using firefox console displayed this error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More] localhost:8000:174:1
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8000/:174`

Comment: well that is your issue :) , jQuery is not defined. So check were you are loading it and make sure that the script in this page is loaded after jQuery.

Comment: @ElenaRoman how can I do this here

Comment: `$('input[name:_token')`- that does not look like a valid selector. All of them should look like `$('input[name="_token"]')`

Comment: @NicoHaase did it but not respond

Comment: No, any solutions

Comment: What do you mean by "not respond"? Have you resolved the error about `$` being not defined before?

Answer (score 0):

you must have forgotten to mention fillable fields in your model `membersmodel`